# Can we use Python Mechanize with Scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, mechanize-python

I am new to Python and Scrapy. I have to auto login my university student portal and then scrape student data out of that website. Can I do the autoLogin with mechanize and then scrape the data with Scrapy? Can both of them be used together? If yes, can anyone please give me an example of it. Thanks.

Comment: I have no experience with mechanize-python, but if you want an alternative you might want to check Selenium + Scrapy. Have a look at this article for an example: http://www.6020peaks.com/2014/12/how-to-scrape-hidden-web-data-with-python/

Comment: mechanize is dead, last update was in 2011... You don't need mechanize to log ing, just do a POST request with your log in details. You can see how to do that by using network inspector in your browser and inspect what's going on when you click the log in button.

Comment: @Granitosaurus is used scrapy auto login instead and it worked well in my case. Thanks alot!